# SQL Delete duplicate values with multiple same columns

Tags: sql

I have a table called report_start that has not have a id column. It has 2 columns called report_id and start_id. A duplicate value is if only report_id and start_İd has matching values with other data in table.

```
report_id-start_id
3-5
2-5
1-4
3-5
```

In above example only 3-5 are duplicate. I want to delete one row from the data. What is the SQL code for that?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only these two columns, then in many databases your only choice is to remove duplicates, empty the table, and re-insert.  This looks like:

```
create temp_t as 
    select distinct t.*
    from t;

truncate table t;   -- backup first!

insert into t
    select *
    from temp_t;
```

Note that the syntax for creating a temporary table depends on the database and may differ.

Some databases have mechanisms for identifying "row id"s of some sort.  That would allow `delete` to be used instead.  However, that is highly database dependent.